# Display Another Data from Other Field if the Data is Empty

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hello Everyone Good Afternoon,

I have 5 Fields in MySQL and there are:

```
ItemCode
Description
OrderQty
ApprovedQty
UoM
UnitPrice
Total
```

I cant explain it using proper words but I hope you will understand it by letting me show to you the table.

```
_______________________________________________________________
|ItemCode|Description|OrderQty|ApprovedQty|UOM|UnitPrice|Total|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|12345678|Ketchup    |12.00   |0.00       |PC |1.00     |12.00|
|67891111|Soy Sauce  |0.00    |12.00      |PC |1.00     |12.00|
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now you see it, I hope you can understand it now.
Here is my Question, I have a Code that will transfer the Data above into a Datagridview but theres a twist and that twist is the Question.

Here it is:

How can I Display the Data like this; If ApprovedQty is 0.00 then the Data in the OrderQty will display but if ApprovedQty is not 0.00 regardless of what data is in the OrderQty the ApprovedQty will be Show.

Something like this.

Based on the Table above

```
___________________________________________________
|ItemCode|Description|OrderQty|UOM|UnitPrice|Total|
---------------------------------------------------
|12345678|Ketchup    |12.00   |PC |1.00     |12.00|
|67891111|Soy Sauce  |12.00   |PC |1.00     |12.00|
---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my code but it only shows the Approved Qty

```
 Private Sub loadfinalpurch1()
        Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=inventory")
        Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select ItemCode,Description,ApprovedQty,UoM,UnitPrice,Total from final_purch where PRnumber = '" & Label2.Text & "' and Added is NULL OR  Added ='';", con1)
        Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
        con1.Open()
        adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
        adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        con1.Close()
        With DataGridView1
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Item Code"
            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Description"
            .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Order Qty"
            .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "UOM"
            .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Unit Price"
            .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Total Amount"
        End With
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Width = 90
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Width = 200
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Width = 90
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Width = 90
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).Width = 100
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).Width = 100
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        Dim checkBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Tag"
        checkBoxColumn.Width = 30
        checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn)

    End Sub
```

I hope you get my point.Do I have something to do with the MYSQL Command? with My Code? I don`t know how to achieve this.

TYSM For Future Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do that condition anywhere, you could do it on your code or directly changing your query:

```
Select ItemCode,
Description,
IF(ApprovedQty = 0, OrderQty, ApprovedQty) as myApprovedQty,
UoM,
UnitPrice,
Total from final_purch where PRnumber = '" & Label2.Text & "' and Added is NULL OR  Added ='';", con1
```

Comment: Really a Great Help Thank You So Much

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this in your SQL using a case statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

The above answers using the IF() function are correct, but in my opinion it is better to use the CASE-WHEN so as to match other database engines like Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the Help, Really a Great Help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
  ItemCode,
  Description,
  IF (ApprovedQty = 0, OrderQty, ApprovedQty),
  UoM,
  UnitPrice,
  Total
FROM table
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thank you for the help really appreciated.